# Playing MP3 chunks with python3

Tags: python-3.x, audio, stream, mp3

In python3 I am sending mp3 audio chunks over the network but I do not know how to play immediately upon received without saving on a file.  Pyaudio only handles wav format.

Comment: update your question to detail your receiving end ... is it a web site with a python server or just a stand alone python server which runs on your computer ( IE. not a remote server )

Comment: It is a stand alone client-server application with udp protocol.